# Automated Testing on Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, automation, automated-tests, outlook-addin

I currently have a Microsoft Outlook add-in that I would like to run automated testing on. I can't seem to find much out there on automation of Outlook so any advice would help. A quick run down of what the script should do is simply open Outlook, click on the correct tab containing the add-in, open the add-in (will appear in a pop up window), and fill out the necessary fields in the add-in and submit. This should all be done without interfering with the user (no moving the mouse etc).

I've taken a look at AutoIT and it seems to be able to handle what I want to do, but I wanted to see if there was anything out there that would be better suited for this task. Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested in the answer, I'm using a combination of AutoIT and 
Selenium to handle my automation. This [link](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/02/selenium-autoit-how-to-automate-non-browser-based-functionality/) was extremely helpful.

Comment: Thanks for posting! I will have a look at it later.